# Equivalence of Knots: why is it a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$ instead of between the two knots

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I'm currently learning about knot theory for the first time from Basic Topology by Armstrong, and he states that two knots $k_1, k_2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ are equivalent if there exists a homeomorphism $h: \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $h(k_1) = k_2$.

My question is: why is it a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, instead of $h: k_1\to k_2$?

Are these statements equivalent, because if I restrict $h: \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ to just $k_1$, and $h^{-1}$ to just $k_2$, then wouldn't this be a homeomorphism between $k_1$ and $k_2$?

Comment: There is always a homeomorphism from $k_1\mapsto k_2$; you can go through $\mathbb{S}^1$. The knot doesn't 'know' it's knotted; it just knows it's a closed curve. It's the embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$ that's knotted.

Comment: Any two knots are homeomorphic to the circle.

Answer (score -1):

I could imagine that it has something to do with that another way to define them, knots are not defined as isotopies, but as **ambient** isotopies. Otherwise, you could "pull at the ends", such that the holes become infinitely small and disappear.

In other words: It could help to preserve the knot's holes within $\mathbb{R}^3$. (Note that it has no holes as a subspace, therefore the disappearance of holes when seen as embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3$ does not contradict that homeomorphisms retain the topology *between the subspaces*.)

Comment: You can also define the equivalence class of a knot by smooth isotopies, which personally I find easier to visualize than an ambient isotopy

Comment: You may be completely right. To be honest, I only once read the definition with ambient isotopies within a paper advocating a rather categorical view which I did not understand utterly, so I do not have a broad perspective.